# Traceback output when adding repository

Tags: 16.04, updates, python, repository

Whenever I add a repository using the `add-apt-repository` command, a Traceback is called regarding the files `/usr/bin/lsb_release` and `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py`

(I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1)

The output is the following when adding a repository:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 98, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 62, in main
    distinfo = lsb_release.get_distro_information(options.upstream)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 344, in get_distro_information
    distinfo = guess_debian_release()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 239, in guess_debian_release
    get_distro_info(distinfo['ID'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 41, in get_distro_info
    RELEASES_ORDER.sort(key=lambda n: float(n[0]))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 41, in <lambda>
    RELEASES_ORDER.sort(key=lambda n: float(n[0]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '6.06 LTS'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 98, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 62, in main
    distinfo = lsb_release.get_distro_information(options.upstream)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 344, in get_distro_information
    distinfo = guess_debian_release()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 239, in guess_debian_release
    get_distro_info(distinfo['ID'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 41, in get_distro_info
    RELEASES_ORDER.sort(key=lambda n: float(n[0]))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 41, in <lambda>
    RELEASES_ORDER.sort(key=lambda n: float(n[0]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '12.04 LTS'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 98, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 62, in main
    distinfo = lsb_release.get_distro_information(options.upstream)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 344, in get_distro_information
    distinfo = guess_debian_release()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 239, in guess_debian_release
    get_distro_info(distinfo['ID'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 41, in get_distro_info
    RELEASES_ORDER.sort(key=lambda n: float(n[0]))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 41, in <lambda>
    RELEASES_ORDER.sort(key=lambda n: float(n[0]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '12.04 LTS'
```

When I remove `/usr/bin/lsb_release`, I don't get that traceback, but in my system tray a red icon is shown to inform me that there's been an error getting the updates.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Might be a bug, consider [filing a bug report on Launchpad](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug), please.

Comment: I find this very odd: '6.06 LTS' And you have tagged it 16.04, but there's 12.04 is mentioned twice. Is this Ubuntu?